# How to add content script on HTML file in extension - chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

As part of an extension I am writing for fun I have dataWDTG.html that I provide in the root of the extension.

The address of my html file is:

```
chrome-extension://RANDOMID/dataWDTG.html
```

In my manifest.json I have:

```
"content_scripts":[
    {
        "matches":[
            "*://*/dataWDTG.html*"
        ],
        "js":["data.js"]
    }
    ],
```

data.js is:

```
//data.js
alert("JS Loaded");
```

However when I open the HTML file I don't get any alert. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Content scripts can't run on chrome-extension:// URLs. You can simply load the js using `<script src="file.js"></script>` tag

Comment: @wOxxOm Will the script be able to use chrome.* methods?

Comment: Yes. Actually, it will be able to use much more than a content script because it'll be running in the full context of the extension.